# Change inage on hover issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I placed this code on another page but for some reason when i put it in a `div` or its own the code will not work and i can't get my rollover image to appear.

Here is my code

```
<div id="container4">
    <a href='bird3.html' onmouseover="document.photo.src='next2.png';" onmouseout="document.photo.src='next.png';">        
    <img src="next.png" name="photo" border="0"> </img>
</div>
```

Comment: This tag doesn't exist: `</img>`

Comment: Obviously I can't see any image in your snippet, but it works.

Comment: I can see on the browser developer tools the image source being toggled, so it works.

Comment: It does look like it's working for me too on the example given? Strange one...? Are you sure it's not a browser problem. Have you cleared your cache etc?

Comment: Define _it doesn't work_.

Comment: i have tried to different computers and it doesn't work

Comment: it's clickable and the first image displays but when I roll over it, it doesn't change to the rollover image

Comment: It's working for at least two people here, including myself. So if you say it's not working for you...

Comment: For the next ones editing the question: **Don't remove parts of the question unless you're the author!**

Comment: I checked and both images have the right now and are the same folder so no idea why it won't work

Comment: I found out the problem i have another rollover image in a different div and it doesn't seem to like both of them but if I take the other one out it seems to work

Comment: So the solution is to give each image an unique `id` and use this to select it: `document.getElementById('your-unique-id').src`

Answer (score 2):

*Such a small code, so many issues:* here's a list

- `img` attribute `name` is invalid <sup>[Allowed IMG Attributes](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/img.html#img-attributes)</sup>
- `</img>` is an invalid closign tag cause `img`  tag is in the set of **Void Elements** <sup>[List of Void Elements](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/syntax.html#void-element)</sup>
- `a` anchor Element is not in the set of **Void elements** and if it has no content **do not use the minified version** of `<a />` <sup>[How to handle empty tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_3)</sup>
- Image `border="0"` tag. **Deprecate it.** Use `style` instead.
- Try to avoid the use of HTML inline `javascript` methods: it's hard to maintain. **Keep your script functions in one place**.
- Try to pre-load all your images to prevent blanks on user-actions. In your code the second image is called on a later request; if not already cached by the browser the user sees nothing until the image is loaded.

What you want ***can be done in pure CSS*** using the `:hover` pseudo selector

```css
div[id^=container] a       + img + img { display:none; }   /*hide second image*/
div[id^=container] a:hover + img + img { display:inline; } /*show second image*/
div[id^=container] a:hover + img       { display:none; }   /*hide  first image*/
```

```html
<div id="container4">
  <a href='bird3.html'>hover me</a>       
  <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40/ccc">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/40x40/cf5">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing an `</a>` tag after the img element ?

Also, as has benn pointed out, get rid of your `</img>` tag and just end your `<img ...` with `/>`

Try clearing your browser cache out and try again. It seems to work in the example given?

Comment: From testing, having a closing `</a>` doesn't allow it to be clickable. It should be self-closing: `<a href='bird3.html' onmouseover="document.photo.src='next2.png';" onmouseout="document.photo.src='next.png';"/>`. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tbwvpjmk/

Comment: Example for this answer: http://codepen.io/tgreenwood/pen/gbMLeB

Comment: @DrewKennedy can you please point to a W3C documentation that says that `<a/>` is valid? http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_3 http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/syntax.html#void-element